# WebView Cocoa control crashing on window close

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, crash, webview, nsdocument

I get a crash in `WebEditorClient::clearUndoRedoOperations` which is trying to access `-[WebView(WebViewEditing) undoManager]` when I close the main window of an NSDocument that contains a webview with a text editor in it. It only happens when there is an undo-able state. Seems like a bug in Cocoa, but I might be doing something wrong. Any ides why this might be going on? The web view is in a nib and not created programmatically, so I'm not sure what I can do to even begin fixing this.

Comment: I agree—bug in Cocoa or bug in WebKit. Either way, you should file a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, removing it from superview prior to calling close on the document seems to have fixed it. Still, that doesn't explain what was going on, but just putting it here in case other people have this problem.